# How to specify method request path variables with aws apigateway CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-api-gateway

I have a route defined in AWS API Gateway that uses a path variable, to be accessed like so:

```
/route/{variable}
```

It is all configured properly and working as I expect, except that I cannot find how to test this route via the CLI.  When I use the AWS Console's "TEST" function on that method, it prompts me to enter the desired value for my variable.  I do this, and it works as expected, with the following appearing in the execution logs:

```
Thu Jan 07 16:30:06 UTC 2016 : Method request path: {variable=my specified value}
Thu Jan 07 16:30:06 UTC 2016 : Method request headers: {}
```

However when I execute it using the CLI with this command:

```
$ aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id {rest-api-id} --resource-id {resource-id} --http-method GET --path-with-query-string 'variable=my specified value'
```

I get a 500 ISE response, with the following in the logs:

```
Thu Jan 07 16:38:20 UTC 2016 : Method request path: {}
Thu Jan 07 16:38:20 UTC 2016 : Method request headers: {}
Thu Jan 07 16:38:20 UTC 2016 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform input
```

I've tried *many* variations on this theme, including using a JSON-encoded string for the `--path-with-query-string` value (e.g. `{"variable":"my specified value"}`), using a raw path (e.g. `/route/my%20specified%20value`), and several others.

I've also tried specifying this value using the `--stage-variables` switch, and making the `--path-with-query-string` value blank.  This yields the same result.

I've been able to get my call to work by specifying `--headers '{"variable":"my specified value"}'` but this doesn't seem correct as it circumvents the path variable, so it isn't a completely valid test.  Is there a way to specify `Method request path` variables using the CLI?  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to issue the command using the full path, i.e.:

$ aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id abc123 --resource-id xyz987 --http-method GET --path-with-query-string '/route/123'

The error message above indicates an error with the request body transformation. You may need to specify a --body parameter, and/or specify accept/content-type headers via the --headers parameter.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: it worked by just adding the full path; no need to mess with the `--body` or `--headers` parameters. Thanks!